# Fantasy Football: Compare a team's average points to the league average?

Tags: php, mysql

I have data for a fantasy football league in a MySQL table.  I want to query the data for a php page.

How do I create a query to calculate a team's points scored compared to the league average points scored for that particular year?

My (simplified) data table looks like this:

game table:

```
year | team | Week | Points
2016 | Wildcats | 1 | 44
2016 | Wildcats | 2 | 52
2015 | Hawks | 1 | 36
2015 | Hawks | 2 | 58
2016 | Hawks | 1 | 43
```

How would I find the difference between the Wildcats' average in 2016 (48.0) and the average of all teams in 2016 (46.3)?

I can calculate those two numbers using this query, but not sure how to do the subtraction.

```
SELECT g1.year, g1.team, AVG(g1.points) as ppg,
    (SELECT AVG(points)
    FROM game AS g2
    WHERE g2.year=g1.year) AS seasAvg
FROM game AS g1
GROUP BY g1.team, g1.year
ORDER BY ppg
```

Comment: It does seem like you can figure this out though; you seem so close.

Comment: yes @Strawberry good to see questions where a genuine effort has been taken and with sample data too. A rarity in these tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the whole thing in an outer query and you can then calculate the difference while keeping it short and sweet.

```
SELECT a.*, ppg - seasAvg AS diff FROM (
    SELECT g1.year, g1.team, AVG(g1.points) as ppg,
        (SELECT AVG(points)
        FROM game AS g2
        WHERE g2.year=g1.year) AS seasAvg
    FROM game AS g1
    GROUP BY g1.team, g1.year
    ORDER BY ppg
) AS a
```